# NSDictionary variable not being passed to other methods

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdictionary

I have a method that takes an NSDictionary from a ViewController and assigns it to a global NSDictionary (cardDictionary) variable in my RequestModel class. cardDictionary is declared as a property (nonatomic, retain) and it is synthesized. That works ok (as verified by NSLog).  Here it is:

```
-(void)findIndexForCardPage:(NSDictionary*)dictionary  {
//parse here and send to a global dictionary
self.cardDictionary = dictionary;
NSLog(@"%@",cardDictionary);
}
```

Now when I try to access that variable in another method, still in the RequestModel class, it is null:

```
-(NSDictionary*)parseDictionaryForCardPage  {
//parse dictionary here for data needed on card page
NSLog(@"%@",cardDictionary);
return cardDictionary;

}
```

This method is called from a viewcontroller class, and cardDictionary is null.  How can I make cardDictionary retain its data from the previous method?  I tried taking out the self from self.cartDictionary...no luck.  Anything else I should know?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that cardDictionary is the global variable, and self.cardDictionary - probably accessing the instance variable.

and in

```
-(NSDictionary*)parseDictionaryForCardPage  {
//parse dictionary here for data needed on card page
NSLog(@"%@",cardDictionary);
return cardDictionary;

}
```

you are accessing the global one. Delete it and use the instance variable.

Comment: That didn't work.  cardDictionary is declared as a property (nonatomic, retain) and it is synthesized.  I tried it without using self, using self on both...nothing.

Comment: do you have a variable called cardDictionary?

Comment: yes.  I did: @property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *cardDictionary; and then @synthesize cardDictionary; also released it in dealloc.

Comment: Sorry, you don't:) @property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *cardDictionary - is property, and not variable. it just points nowhere. you have to declare the variable: MyClass : NSObject { NSDictionry* cardDictionary; } @property(nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *cardDictionary; @end

Comment: I think it has to to with me calling -(NSDictionary*)parseDictionaryForCardPage from another class.  If I call it from RequestModel everything works.  Still, it should retain the value of cardDictionary...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your second call (parseDictionaryForCardPage) is using the same instance of RequestModel that the first call (findIndexForCardPage) is?

Comment: yes, i am sure.  i've tested it by calling both methods and printing the value in the log.  however, this does not work when i call parseDictionaryForCardPage from another class.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code, then.  Specifically, how and where you make the first call and how and where you make the second call.

Answer (score 0):

You property in RequestModal class should be declared as retained:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary* cardDictionary;
```

In the @implementation section of class RequestModal you should synthesize property:

```
@synthesize cardDictionary;
```

and this method is correct:

```
-(void)findIndexForCardPage:(NSDictionary*)dictionary  {
//parse here and send to a global dictionary
self.cardDictionary = dictionary;
NSLog(@"%@",cardDictionary);
}
```

In this method you should add self. to the name of property:

```
-(NSDictionary*)parseDictionaryForCardPage  {
//parse dictionary here for data needed on card page
NSLog(@"%@",self.cardDictionary);
return cardDictionary;

}
```

Comment: I've already had cardDictionary declared as a property.  This isn't working for me.  Could it be due to me calling -(NSDictionary*)parseDictionaryForCardPage  from another class?